# Krita won't read folders Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: krita

Krita won't read folders Ubuntu 19.04 !

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Which Krita package is installed, the apt package or the snap package?

Comment: Oh ! I just deleted Krita and reinstalled Krita with this

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kritalime/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install krita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Krita can be installed from Ubuntu Software as either an apt package or a snap package. I recommend the apt package over the snap package for all image editing applications because it is more stable. Unlike the snap packages it never crashes for me, so there's a lower probability of using your work if you don't save it every few minutes, which by the way you should always do.

To install Krita in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install krita
```